# Added vHost with Port 8080, now Port 80 doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, macos, xampp, symfony1

I want to use port 8080 for my symfony-project and port 80 for my old project in the htdocs folder. localhost:8080 does work, but localhost:80 has no server connection. how can i use both (port 80 and 8080)?

Here is my config:

```
Listen 8080
Listen 80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/cs/bp/app/web"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "/Users/cs/bp/app/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf /Users/cs/bp/app/lib/symfony/1.4/data/web/sf
  <Directory "/Users/cs/bp/app/lib/symfony/1.4/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
    Require all granted

  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your apache conf you have:

```
Listen 8080
Listen 80

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
web server confs here
</VirtualHost>
```

but I dont see anything for port :80 entry. You should create

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
web server confs here
</VirtualHost>
```

entry. Make sure you restart apache and also look out for any messages from the output.

Comment: You also have "AllowOverride All" You should set that to None if you're going to be using .htaccess just fyi.